# Output impedance refers to open circuit o/p impedance or short circuit o/p impedance?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, impedance, characteristic-impedance

When we specify output impedance of a two port network, does it imply open circuit output impedance or short circuit output impedance? [Wikipedia: output impedance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/output_impedance) ; [Wikipedia: two-port network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/two-port_network)

[image: Two port]

g22 (Short-circuit output impedance) = $$\dfrac{V_2}{I_2}|_{V_1=0}$$
z22 (Open-circuit output impedance) =  $$\dfrac{V_2}{I_2}|_{I_1=0}$$

For eg: When we say an ideal amplifier should have low output impedance, does it imply g22 or z22?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable *g* is used for what are called the *inverse hybrid network parameters*. It is indeed defined as

\$g_{22}=\dfrac{v_2}{i_2}|_{v_1=0}\$

The inverse hybrid parameters are very rarely used in practice, and they don't have conventional names except "the inverse hybrid parameter \$g_{22}\$".

The *z* parameters are conventionally called the *impedance parameters*. If someone tells you they are giving you an impedance value, it should mean the *z*-parameter if they don't tell you otherwise.

In many useful networks (for example, well-designed amplifiers) there is sufficient directivity such that it doesn't really matter whether the input is open-circuited or short-circuited when measuring or specifying the output impedance. But for general networks you should indeed consider the input as open-circuit when determining \$z_{22}\$.

> Is thevenin equivalent impedance, seen from output port has any connection with g22 or z22 ?

Let's look at the equivalent circuits implied by the two types of network parameters:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEx7Z7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can see that the Z-parameters describe a network as if it has a Thevenin-like circuit at each port, with the source value being dependent on the current in to the other port.

For the inverse hybrid parameters, there's a Thevenin-like circuit on port 2, but a Norton-like circuit on port 1.

Looking at these equivalents also shows you why you have to take the controlling variable from the other port to be 0 to find \$z_{22}\$ or \$g_{22}\$. If you didn't take the other independent variable to 0, the output wouldn't depend just on what's connected to port 2, it would also depend on the conditions at port 1.

Comment: one doubt: Is thevenin equivalent impedance, seen from output port has any connection with
g22 or z22
? What I have seen is Thevenin equivalent impedance is usually defined for a one-port network.Does it make any sense to extend it to 2 port?

Answer (score 1):

It's the equivalent of sticking a resistor on the output of a zero impedance output

Answer (score 1):

> When we specify output impedance of a two port network, does it imply
>   open circuit output impedance or Thévenin equivalent impedance(short
>   circuit output impedance)?

If an output produces a 1V signal when open circuit and can drive a 10mA current signal when short circuited, the output impedance is 1V/10mA = 100 ohms.

It's the same as have a perfect voltage generator with zero output impedance (impossible and theoretical) in series with a 100 ohm resistor.